# What is a good methodology for adding menu links if a bundle is enabled

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm developing an Application in Symfony2 (twig templating) which will involve multiple bundles some of which may be swapped out in place of others. Each bundle will provide certain URLs and functionality at that URL.

What is a good practice for building up a menu full of links depending on what bundles are enabled?

My first thought is using twig to embed a controller that will check the kernel.bundles parameter and depending on that list build a menu on it. But I also may have to have sub navigation links open if the parent link is selected and I'm unsure as how to implement this yet.

Comment: Take a look in the Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller class. There is a lot of services that depends on bundle that are enabled or not. getDoctrine is a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For menus in general, you should have a look at the [KnpMenuBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle).

About your bundle problematic: I would suggest an approach with [tagged services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html).

Every bundle could contain a submenu service, that is tagged. In your main menu implementation you could have a menu registry, that collects all those tagged services.